# Proving $\|fg\|_{L^1} \leq \|f\|_{L^p}^{\alpha} \|g\|_{L^q}^{1-\alpha}$

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, measure-theory, inequality, lp-spaces

I am trying to prove the following inequality:
$$\|fg\|_{L^1} \leq \|f\|_{L^p}^{\alpha}\|g\|_{L^q}^{1-\alpha}$$
where
$$\quad 1= \frac1{p} +\frac1{q}, \quad 1 \leq p, q, \leq \infty.$$
In particular, we may choose $\alpha = 1/p$.

This seems very closely related to Hölder's inequality and some kind of $L^p$ interpolation, but I have been unsuccessful so far, especially with getting the correct exponents $\alpha$ and $1-\alpha$. How can I prove this? Moreover, is there a name for this inequality? I am thinking that this may only be true in bounded domains.

Comment: This is wrong. It does not hold for any $\alpha$.

Comment: Let $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ and write down the resulting inequality with $f$ (or $g$) replaced by $\lambda f$ (or $\lambda g$). Play with the values of $\lambda$ and see what the consequences of this inequality would be.

Comment: The homogeneity of LHS and RHS with respect to $f$ and $g$ do not fit. Perhaps you can modify the inequality to for example $$\|fg\|_1\le |f\|_{p/\alpha}\|g\|_{q/(1-\alpha)}$$ The inequality holds for some instances of $L^p$ spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f$ and $g$ be any positive functions for which all the integrals here are finite. Replacing $f$ by $nf$ we see that we must have  $1 \leq \alpha$. Replacing $g$ by $ng$ we see that $1 \leq 1-\alpha$. We have obtained a contradiction.